# What is the difference between group and container controls in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

**Flex** has both group and Skinnablecontainer controls like **Group, VGroup, HGroup, BorderContainer**. Any one can tell me the difference between group and container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has to be more generic like **Differences between Skinnablecontainers and Group**

**Explanation:**

The `border container` extends SkinnableContainer, so skinClass can be applied to the skinnable container, So, along with children, we can skin the way the container looks by using these containers. These are a little heavy weight components as it has to draw skin every time the user tries to do invalidation on the component.

`Groups` are light weight containers. these are used only to layout children, you will not be given tools to apply skin on it as they are used only to display children(children can have their own skin).

More on it [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSF1E2E7DD-8FA6-408d-9652-4B5E57A85A5A.html)

Comment: Mark it as answered if it answers your question. thanks.